# Authentication with WebApi & AspNet.Identity 3

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt, asp.net-identity-3

What is the best authentication solution for a WebAPI/AspNet.Identiy 3.0-*/SPA architecture?

It seems that OAuth 2.0 JWT bearer token is a better approach vs coockies. But I could not find up to date examples with AspNet.Identity 3. Does anyone knows what to do in order to generate JWT with Identity?

Comment: [This](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/) article seems quite valid as it uses the latest Identity (2.1)?

Comment: I am working with the last beta version of Asp.Net/Identity and I am not sure that the solution in the article is still the right way to do it.